# DRCSIM: new API and update rate

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for publishing the preliminary API
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide.

With regard to the control inputs (subscriptions).

What is the fastest update rate that can be published and received by Gazebo for drcsim?

What is the control loop update rate in simulation time?

What is the expected physics simulation time step?

One can imagine running physics simulation at 0.001 s time step, but simulating a 200 Hz controller at 0.005 second time step (that is control output only updated every 5th simulation time step).

If the physics is only run at 0.005 s, then there is no point designing a controller that depends on 500 hz update rate.

Can you give us guidance on plans and expectations regarding the above questions?  This will constrain the control methods that can be used.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/946/drcsim:--new-api-and-update-rate/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-01-21**:
I note that the message description uses continuous notation (1/s, s), and not discrete time controller (1/z, z) notation.  If intentional, this would imply that controller must run at same update rate as physics, but given limited setpoint update rate would still function as discrete time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The API docs are expanding in advance of the drcsim 2.0 release.  Your questions are now addressed [there](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#Atlas).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0